# Gevent start() method won't start new thread, when executed from python console

Tags: python, pycharm, gevent

Gevent thread won't start on calling start() method, when running from PyCharm console, but only when join() is called. 
Why?

```
Python 3.6.3 (default, Oct  4 2017, 06:09:38) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.37)] on darwin
import gevent
def dummy():
    for _ in range(10):
        print("Dummy!")
g = gevent.Greenlet(dummy)
g.start()

# Nothing happens ....

g.join()
Dummy!
Dummy!
Dummy!
Dummy!
Dummy!
Dummy!
Dummy!
Dummy!
Dummy!
Dummy!
```